# Locally stored json array is printing but value from json is giving undefined in cordova application

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova

Hello I am new to JSON I have searched a lot but nothing is working for me. my problem is I am saving data using local storage in JSON and when I am trying to print array it's working fine.but it is not giving the values.

**Here is my code for storing data in JSON-**

```
var user;
var users;
   function saveData(){

   if ('localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
       try {
            user = JSON.stringify({ 
                email : $("#email").val(), 
                timestamp : $("#time").val(),
              }),

           users = localStorage.getItem('user');
           users = users ? JSON.parse(users) : [];
           users.push(user);

           localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(users)); 
           alert("The data was saved."); 
           return true;
       } catch (e) {
           if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR) {
               alert('Quota exceeded!');
           } 
       }
       } else {
           alert('Cannot store user preferences as your browser do not support local storage');
       } 
    }
```

**and I am getting this here**

```
  function showData(user_email){
    user_email = {};
   user_email = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
     for(index in user_email){
         alert(user_email[index].email);
     }  
 }
```

if I am printing

```
alert(user_email[index]);
```

it is working fine but

```
 alert(user_email[index].email);
```

this gives me undefined.Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: If you use `console.log(user_email[index])` you'll see the entire object listed in the console window. Does the `email` property exist as you expect?

Comment: yes it is existing.it's giving me "{"email":"q","timestamp":"16:39:35"}"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to stringify user object before you push it to array. Users array is an array of objects, not strings. Otherwise you will get a string back for user after `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))` not object as expected.

It should be just:

```
user = { 
    email : $("#email").val(), 
    timestamp : $("#time").val(),
};
```

Comment: still it is saying undefined

Comment: Make sure you clear previously stored incorrect values. Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/7gyjL787/

Comment: when i alert(user_email[index]) it gives me [object object] why so?

Comment: Because `user_email[index]` is an object. When you try to alert object its `toString` method is called which by default returns string `[object Object]`. Use console.log instead of alert.